# Using single select query get the Minimum,Maximum values of Identity Columns of all the tables in a Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using a single select query, I need to get the Minimum and Maximum values of Identity Columns along with the other columns specified in the query below, for all tables in a given database.

This is what I've been able to code to get a list of tables and their identity columns:

```
Select so.name as TableName
,      sic.name as ColumnName
,      i.Rows Count_NumberOfRecords
,      IDENT_CURRENT(so.name)+IDENT_INCR(so.name) as NextSeedValue
from       sys.identity_columns sic
inner join sys.objects          so  on sic.object_id = so.object_id
inner join sys.sysindexes       I   ON So.OBJECT_ID = I.ID
Where so.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' and last_value is not null and indid IN (0,1);
```

The query needs to get these extra columns:

```
MaximumValue (IdentityColumn) and MinimumValue (IdentityColumn) for each table.
```

Comment: So, you're having a problem with what exactly?  Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: `Select so.name as TableName
 ,      sic.name as ColumnName
 ,      i.Rows Count_NumberOfRecords
 ,      IDENT_CURRENT(so.name)+IDENT_INCR(so.name) as NextSeedValue
 from       sys.identity_columns sic
 inner join sys.objects          so  on sic.object_id = so.object_id
 inner join sys.sysindexes       I   ON So.OBJECT_ID = I.ID
 Where so.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' and last_value is not null and indid IN (0,1)`

Comment: havent you heard about aggregate funtions ever?

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: But the Question is for each table in the database we need a single select query. Without using cursor/loops

Comment: Nobody mentioned anything about a cursor or loop. There is absolutely no need for any kind of looping for something like this.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Have a +1 for framing your question properly and showing the work you've attempted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use something along these lines:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(max);
SET @cmd = '';

SELECT @cmd = @cmd + CASE WHEN (@cmd = '') THEN '' ELSE ' UNION ALL ' END + 'SELECT ''' + 
    QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ''' AS TableName, ''' + 
    QUOTENAME(c.name) + ''' AS ColumnName, MAX(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') AS MaxID, MIN(' + 
    QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') AS MinID, COALESCE(IDENT_CURRENT(''' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + 
    QUOTENAME(t.name) + '''),0) + COALESCE(IDENT_INCR(''' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + 
    QUOTENAME(t.name) + '''),0) AS NextValue FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) 
FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE c.is_identity = 1

SELECT @cmd; /* Shows the dynamic query generated, not necessary */

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
```

The query uses dynamic SQL to construct a `UNION` query that gathers the Table Name, Column Name, and Min and Max ID values currently in every table that has an `IDENTITY` field.

You could quite easily modify this to show the columns in the format you want, along with the other columns you mention in your question.

I've edited the query above to include the "NextValue" field, however I agree with @AaronBertrand in that this value is of little use, since in a busy system it will most certainly be wrong immediately (or shortly thereafter) once the query executes.

Comment: Max, Is there a way without using the dynamic SQL too.

Comment: Maybe, but why?  This answers the question correctly and without too much hassle.  Plus it doesn't use any nasty cursors or loops, and is completely set-based, so SQL Server should be able to come up with a nice plan.

Comment: I noticed you marked this as the answer, then unmarked it.  Was there some problem with the answer?

Comment: @user no loops, no cursors, no dynamic SQL - are you trying to restrict us to magic?

Comment: I could not get the calculated IDENT_CURRENT(so.name)+IDENT_INCR(so.name) as NextSeedValue

Comment: @user do you really have tables where there is an identity column but the increment is not 1? Do you really need to use IDENT_CURRENT when MAX() - which you already have - is probably more reliable anyway? Do you really have ad hoc cowboys running DBCC CHECKIDENT and reseeding your tables? (In either case, someone could insert a bunch of rows after your query starts but before you start reading the results, and certainly long after the query has finished but while you are still looking at the results, so what use is NextSeedValue anyway?)

Comment: In other words, are you solving problems you don't actually have? Are you pulling information not because you need it because it's a checkbox for some report output somewhere?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I understand your point. Its for a report.I got the calculation of next seed value. Thank you

Comment: I've edited the question to include the `IDENT_CURRENT()` and `IDENT_INCR()` values.

Comment: @MaxVernon Is there a way with cte to get this without using dynamic SQL

Comment: No.  A CTE is just a glorified join.  The issue here is you must get the list of tables from the system schema tables and perform operations *on* those tables.  Dynamic SQL allows you to build a statement to execute to get the details required.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you *not* want to use Dynamic SQL?

Comment: @MaxVernon This needs to be executed on multiple production databases using a single wrapper script. It would be good if we have single select statement.

Comment: What language is your wrapper script using?  If you add the wrapper script to your question, perhaps I can modify it so "it just works".